# Xcode build settings to swap service URLs

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have a plist with a collection of URLs that my app utilizes.

I'd like to setup some sort of 1-click "scheme" or whatever within Xcode so that I can swap my app between the test server URLs and the live server URLs. I could either create a second plist with the test URLs or could do some string manipulation to change the host name after reading them.

How should I set this up? I'm starting from scratch here as I've never played with custom targets or anything.

Answer (score 2):

Create two different lists. You can use preprocessor macros to find out what configurations is used:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
    // use test URLs list
#else
    // use production URLs list
#endif
```

If you created the project in Xcode 4, it probably already has the DEBUG macro defined for Debug configuration. If you are not sure, go to Build Settings of the project and check the compiler preprocessing section. Preprocessor Macros row for Debug configuration should have DEBUG or DEBUG=1 string.

[image]

Comment: Can I have a custom "scheme" so that my otherwise non-debug code can be built with the test urls just by picking that in the scheme drop-down?

Comment: Yes you can. Go to Edit Scheme... dialog. Press Duplicate Scheme to make a copy of the scheme. Rename the copy to something like Debug Project or Release Project depending on your needs. Select the appropriate Build Configuration for it. Enjoy :)

Comment: It's the specifics of this process that I'm looking for. I may just create a new project to play around with how to do this before "corrupting" my app's project file with experimentation.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the Other C flags build setting which can be set differently for different build configurations.

Something like: `-DUSE_PRODUCTION_URLS=1`

Here's a [reference](http://www.gotow.net/creative/wordpress/?p=40).